# Swift 4: Navigation Controller unwanted looping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, sdk

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if AccessToken.current != nil {
            // Already logged-in
            // Redirect to Home View Controller
            goToHome()
        }

        // Add LoginButton
        let loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile, .email, .userFriends ])
        let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height // real screen height
        //let's suppose we want to have 10 points bottom margin
        let newCenterY = screenHeight - loginButton.frame.height - 20
        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: newCenterY)
        loginButton.center = newCenter
        view.addSubview(loginButton)

        // Triggered after every successfully login / logout
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AccessTokenDidChange, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] _ in
            if AccessToken.current != nil {
                // Successfully just Logged in
                // Redirect to Home View Controller
                self?.goToHome()
            } else {
                // Successfully just Logged out
            }
        }
    }

    func goToHome() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeAfterLogIn", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeAfterLogInViewController") // I called mine like that (check screenshot below)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

This code lets a user log into my app using Facebook SDKs. The LaunchScreen.storyboard is as follows:

[image]

Which then leads to the Main.storyboard, which looks like this:

[image]

If the user's login is successful, they will be taken to HomeAfterLogIn.storyboard, shown below:

[image]

However, this page continuously loads once the user is logged in i.e. the user is successfully logged in, the "Logged In" label is shown, and then it reloads over and over again, whereas I just want it to load once. If the user has previously logged in, the page only loads once which is the following code:

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
            // Already logged-in
            // Redirect to Home View Controller
            goToHome()
        }
```

But if the user is a new user / first time user, it will loops so I think the error is here:

```
// Triggered after every successfully login / logout
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AccessTokenDidChange, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] _ in
            if AccessToken.current != nil {
                // Successfully just Logged in
                // Redirect to Home View Controller
                self?.goToHome()
            } else {
                // Successfully just Logged out
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your last screenshot that for your HomeAfterLogInViewController in the `storyboard` you have set the **Custom Class class** attribute to `ViewController` that means that you are linking that UI of HomeAfterLogInViewController with `ViewController.swift` and it seems you are in a loop.

Every storyboard UI ViewController must be linked to a swift class represent the specific ViewController logic.

**That means in your last screenshot, where you see on the right Custom Class replace ViewController with `HomeAfterLogInViewController`** (which should be the same name of a file you have as `HomeAfterLogInViewController.swift`)

[image]

Comment: problem fixed! The app is working perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hey there — here's some similar code that hopefully helps :

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let signedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "signedIn")

    if(signedIn) {
        let HomeVC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = HomeVC2
    } else {
        let signInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EntryVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = signInVC
    }

    return true
}
```

I saw that you had something nearly identical, but it looks like adding "if" "else" "return" in this structure might solve the issue. Granted, I'm using Firebase as my auth, so it's possible that the structure is different.

You're saying that the same screen keeps popping up? Even after you click through to the next VC? It's possible you might have something on the storyboard messing this up, but let me know if you have more details on this. Hopefully this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Yay, awesome — no problem! :)